# Datastructures: What is a T-table?

Tags: data-structures

In my CS class they were talking about T-tables to implement a cryptography function. They never explained what T-tables are.

What is a T-table?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. This was a tougher search than I thought. What a T-table is defined in the AES specification itself and it refers more to a mathematical notation thingy for convenience's sake than anything else.

The definition is:

> We define tables T0 to T3. These are 4 tables with 256 4-byte word entries and make up for 4KByte of total space.

Quickly thereafter they are referenced in the following paragraph.

> In the final round, there is no MixColumn operation. This boils down to the fact that the S table
>   must be used instead of the T tables. The need for additional tables can be suppressed by
>   extracting the S table from the T tables by masking while executing the final round.

So a T table is a table with random values.

Source: https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/documents/aes-development/rijndael-ammended.pdf (see 5.2.1)